# Linking Java Test Automation with Microsoft Test Manager, TFS , Test Cases

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

Not sure if anyone has encountered this issue previously but having a look couldn't find much relating to my problem.

Scenario:

So currently on my team we've created automation using a Project, Java, Selenium and the page object model. 
We've implemented this over the past year and build upon as new features are implemented.

What we are lacking though is linking this automation to the test cases we create in MTM, as it seems you can only link using visual studio.

Has anyone else encountered this, can we import our eclipse project into visual studio and make the link this way ?

Or any other solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Java test is not supported in MTM, please track this user voice:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/11386173-enable-java-automated-test-to-execute-from-mtm-and